# Adding ngIf condition for ngFor values

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I have a ngFor where i bring all the data. Now i need to hide some buttons if the status is inactive. I am thinking of using ngIf for that. But i don't get how to write the condition for that. How do i check whether the status is inactive and add NgIf condition for those?

```
<tbody id="address-list"  *ngIf="addressData">
   <tr *ngFor="let full of addressData " class="{{full.status}}style show-{{full.status}}" data-target="#address-details-modal" data-toggle = "modal" (click)="seperateId(full.ID)">
   <td class="{{full.status}}style show-{{full.status}}"  >
      {{full.address1}} {{full.address2}}
   </td>
   <td class="{{full.status}}style show-{{full.status}}">
      {{full.type}}
   </td>
   <td class="{{full.status}}style show-{{full.status}}">
      {{full.status}}
   </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Now if the status is inactive. When i edit that. I should hide the edit and delete buttons.

```
 <div class="modal-footer">
   <span class="action-btns" *ngIf="active">
   <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md edit-btn pull-left" title="Edits" id="edit-btn-address" (click)="editModal()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button>
   <button class="btn btn-danger btn-md delete-btn pull-left" title="Make Inactive" id="remove-btn-address" (click)="makeInactive()" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" ></span></button>
   <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default close-btn pull-right">Close</button>
   </span>
   <span class="edit-btns" *ngIf="edit" >
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default cancel-btn" (click)="editm()">Cancel</button>
   <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary saveEqualBtn save-btn"    (click) = "TableUpdate(addressid.ID)" [disabled]="!addressHistory.form.valid" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
   </span>
   <span class="confirm-btns pull-left " *ngIf="inactive" >
   <span >Make Inactive?</span>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default no-btn" (click)="makeInactive()" >No</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger yes-btn" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="AddressInactive(addressid.ID)" >Yes</button>
   </span>
</div>
```

For that i need to have a ngIf value. So that on click those will be Hidden. How Do i do that??

Comment: Do your objects from the ngFor have a inactive property?

Comment: Yes. The status of some objects is inactive. So when i click on them depending on Status buttons should hide.

Comment: @RahulSingh i didnt get what you were asking me to do? I opened the link. Should i log in ?

Comment: Yes prakash please login its a comment section where i make use of this kind of stuff

Comment: I tried to login with google. But its not logging in. @RahulSingh

Comment: @Prakash may be you are behind a proxy or firewall give if a few seconds to boot up after loggin in anyways . I have used renderer 2 for the same

Comment: OK. Can you tell me how can i hide or show button depending on their status? Can i write if condition while i open the modal? Like `if(status = = inactive) { this.inactive = false}` Something like this. I tried this. But it's hiding even for active ones.

Comment: you need to do like this  if(status === 'inactive') if inactive is a string

Answer (score 1):

If you have the property you want you can just compare it

```
<span class="confirm-btns pull-left " *ngIf="obj.property==='inactive'" >
```

Comment: I want to add `ngIf = "inactive"` and then using the `ngIf` i want to hide the buttons. I need to know. How to write the condition where i will add `ngIf ` only to the inactive status.

Comment: You dont add the ngIf only to the inactive status you use it to check if it is inactive. You can surround the buttons with a div class and put the ng if there or put it in the buttons directly.